# How do I make the installer project require the user to restart their machine after installation completes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

As title says, How do I tell the user via  installer that the machine needs to be restarted and have the installer restart it ?

Please note that I'd like to avoid having a custom action with

```
MessageBox.Show("Restart your machine");
```

Comment: Won't Windows Installer do this for you automatically if any changes require a restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify the MSI with Orca to get this working. This isn't possible in C# even though it is in C++. You have to add in the Property Table: `name=REBOOT`, `value=Force`

Comment: Ok I got the Orca, how do I find that property? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I believe you had to add a row in 'Property'

Comment: I've added a row in the "Property" table : NeedReboot = TRUE. However there seems to be no effect. Is that a correct row name?

Comment: Ok. You have to add in Property table, name=REBOOT, value=force.

Comment: Yup, just found it myself as well. Thank you for your input Jan

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but this is the very last thing you should be causing to be required - any subservient component that really requires this should already be setting the 'reboot required' state.

Comment: I'm installing a win32 service, and it doesn't say it requires it.

Comment: Can't you simply start the service as part of your installation process?

Comment: Nope, it needs to be restarted

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you assemble your installer with `RebootCheck.exe` 
You get this RebootCheck.exe from VWD 2008 EE setup explore setup disk & go to VWDExpress\WCU

Then check your setup he worked fine.
For more information try it online